# Agenda js job executes immediately

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda/) to run schedules events on my server.
I'm scheduling a job using this code:

```
var job = global.agenda.create('send happy hour notification', {});
job.repeatEvery('0 21 * * *');
job.unique({});
job.save();
```

So the job should run everyday at 21:00.
But every time my server starts it runs this job..
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

By default any repeating job will execute on the repeating interval you schedule it to AND immediately. The last part is key: by default a repeating agenda will run immediately after you define it. To change this default behavior you pass `skipImmediate: true` to "options". Something like this:

```
job.repeatEvery('3 minutes', {
  skipImmediate: true
});
await job.save();
```

The above will only run when 3 minutes comes around and every 3 minutes after, as opposed to NOW and in 3 minutes and every 3 minutes after.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and so I did some digging and found out that it happens because while saving it fails to calculate nextRunAt correctly, so just run   "job.computeNextRunAt();" before saving your job, and it should be working fine.

Comment: thanks this worked for me, but for some reason it only works if I use the cron job syntax and not if I use a time string.